# windows genuine advantage blocking remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I have a remote server that has just run through a windows update. The server has rebooted and seems to be fine.

However, I can no longer connect via remote desktop. Someone in my office tells me they had a similar problem with a server here and it was a "genuine advantage" tool wanting to be completed.

Is there a way to get the tool to complete its install without visiting the physical server?

Comment: So did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @tomfanning, in the end I rang the hosting company and paid someone to physically go to the server and run through the install (sorry for the slow response)

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting with the /admin or /console switch (depending on what version of the client you have)

```
mstsc /admin
mstsc /console
```

Nothing will appear different about the client from there on in, that's normal.

This should allow you to connect to the console session, where you should be able to complete WGA.

Answer (score 0):

visit this url http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/ it runs the wga setup. Although It seems odd that this has affected your Remote desktop.  Has the update run changed or enabled the windows firewall?

Comment: and on the left is the validate windows this will install the WGA plugin

Comment: How is he supposed to do this without physically visiting the server though?

Comment: I missed that part sorry....

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue. Setting up a XP Pro client to connect to Terminal server.

I did notice that whenever I logged into the admin account on the client it kept asking me to complete the installation of the genuine advantage tool, but I kept clicking cancel. For some reason I could not connect to the terminal server however network was up 100%.

So as a last ditch effort I completed the installation of the genuine advantage tool and hey presto remote desktop connection now connects to the terminal server.

Interesting issue, but on not visiting the physical server, hmmm.... thats a stupid one because sometimes the tool needs user intervention but if you can't connect remotely, all I can say is "good one" MS.

Can't try this myself but try sending an administrative restart from the client. Could be that the WGA hasn't finished installing yet.